# How to pass ID to action.java in struts?

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-1

**I have this code in jsp file :**

```
<%
    int j = 1;
    while (variableTypesIterator.hasNext()) {
        VariableType c = new VariableType();
        c = variableTypesIterator.next();
        if (variableTypeId != null && c.getVariableTypeId().equals(variableTypeId)) {
%>
<br/>
<li><label><%=c.getVariableTypeId()%>
</label> <html:link action="/policyBasicInfo.do?method=selectedVariableType"
                    style="text-decoration: none;"><%=c.getVariableTypeName()%>
</html:link></li>
<%
} else {
%>
<br/>
<li><html:link action="/policyBasicInfo.do?method=selectedVariableType"
               style="text-decoration: none;"><%=c.getVariableTypeName()%>
</html:link></li>
<input type="VtId" id="VtId" name="VtId" value="<%=c.getVariableTypeId()%>"/>
<%
        }
        j++;
    }
%>
<%
    }
%>
```

**How to pass ID ( Input text Value ) to action File in struts?**
**When the user Click link?**

Comment: you need to call the .do from javascript and submit the form by getting input text value as an url parameter to action.

Comment: i mean when user clicks call a javascript function and inside that function call the .do with the  ( Input text Value )

Comment: You mean via Ajax? Or just creating a link with the parameter and setting the window location to that? Unrelated, but that JSP is really hard to read :(

Comment: What the linked action is doing? Why do you use a link instead of a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier approach will be

```
<a href="/policyBasicInfo.do?method=selectedVariableType&variableTypeId=<%=c.getVariableTypeId()%>"><%=c.getVariableTypeName()%></a>
```